# How much traffic comes to us from non-search engines sources?

Tags: support

Kinda in the same line of [this question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8745/can-we-improve-the-path-from-ubuntu-com-to-here), exactly how much traffic comes to us from other sources? This will give us a very specific view of how can we improve our stop-gap before users ask questions without the ["minimum research effort"](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) that the SE model ask for any of us.

Answer (score 3):

Over 90% of traffic to Ask Ubuntu comes from Search Engines. I'm not sure how that information helps improve anything, but the majority of traffic to all the Stack Exchange sites are search engine driven.

Comment: That means that 1 out 10 users (average?) comes without doing a search first, translated to 36k/day, which is very large number. I was more interested in what was the other 10% of referrers about.

Comment: Does that include _all_ traffic or only users who actually post questions? I think @Braiam is interested in the latter.

Comment: @Braiam Even if this were specifically traffic for posted questions, it would not mean that 1 of 10 didn't search first. It would mean 1 out of 10 users comes from somewhere *other than* the search they did (or may have done) first. For example, someone could search in another browser tab or window, or in the same tab/window but go to some other site (e.g., http://ubuntu.com) in between, or a variety of other likely possibilities. And the people who *do* come here from a search engine didn't necessarily search for their problem first; for example, they may just have typed in "ubuntu help."