# How to request to remove "marked as duplicate" and to reopen?

Tags: support, closed-questions

My [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433248/check-dependencies-and-generate-download-script-before-installing-by-dpkg) is marked as duplicate a month ago. I have edited and improved question and **flagged** today to reopen but It isn't reopened. Thus, Is there any chances of reopening? or I should post new question and delete old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, editing a closed question in the 1st 5 days after closure [automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/203101) puts it into the [reopen review queue](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8745/85695). Once there, it needs 5 people to vote for it to be reopened before it is reopened.

Now, your particular question *is* a duplicate and it should not be reopened. You are basically asking how to detect dependencies for deb packages and the dupe answers that very well. You can't expect us to simply write the script for you, you need to do some of the work yourself. So, if your question is actually "Please write my script for me", it is off topic, we're not a script writing service. If your question is "How can I detect dependencies" then the dupe answers it.

Answer (score 3):

1. You need more than 1 person to vote it to re-open to re-open a question OR a moderator to step in and re-open it.
2. How is it not a duplicate? (the question is was closed against seems the same to me and the accepted answer in the question answers your question).

Comment: I re edited and clarified my question.