# What are the features of Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: support

What are the features of Ask Ubuntu??

Comment: Can you explain more precisely what you mean?

Comment: Features like posting a question,deleting etc etc..Can anyone list all the feautures of askubuntu..??

Comment: Have you seen [How does Ask Ubuntu work?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/257/)  This seems like a duplicate, or at least reading that post and all the linked content would greatly help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a ton of features on Ask Ubuntu - However, the platform is designed to be "Documentation through Discovery". So you won't find a list of features - StackExchange keeps things "interesting" by always adding and changing features and letting the user discover how to use the site. If you're wondering "What things can I discover" you may wish to view your [available privileges](https://askubuntu.com/privileges). This should give you an idea of what to look forward to and what you can do now.

Answer (score 3):

I found [askubuntu.com/review](https://askubuntu.com/review)

This shows low rep new users, it's useful for guiding new users on how to use the site, etc. [Low quality posts](https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts) is pretty useful too -- though I suspect it's mostly useful for people who do a ton of editing and/or moderation than the average user.

[More information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer) on the parent meta.

Answer (score 0):

> the platform is designed to be "Documentation through Discovery ...  letting the user discover how to use the site". So you won't find a list of features ...

I really like Ubuntu & the very helpful community. A website called 'Ask Ubuntu' will attract anyone with a query but unfortunately it's not at all clear how to navigate the site. It needs a Site Map and a simple Site Guide & a Users Guide. eg the Front Screen needs something like:

**"Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

1/ Pose your question in the box at the top left of the screen to see if it's been asked before.

2/ If not then Register yourself and

3/ ASK your question by typing it in the box at xxx.

4/ You'll find how to format your question by clicking on yyy which you will find at zzz"**

Not only will this help anyone new to the site to use it: it might well increase the takeup of Ubuntu & other flavours generally.

I expect this has been explored before, but I can't find it [poor navigation skills? or sophisticated site design?!?]

Comment: You may find a new question asking for this feature or help with navigation would be better than posting an answer to this 7 year old out dated question. This is unlikely to receive many views or comments here.