# How do I quickly gain reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

What is the simplest way to up your reputation points so that one can use all features offered by this site?

Answer (score 44):

Short version: Ask good questions and give good answers.

- [How does Ask Ubuntu work?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/257/how-does-ask-ubuntu-work)

Comment: +1 for teaching by example. :)

Comment: The answer not really practical. How to give good answer lacking the experience? Why to ask good questions instead of what you want to know?

Comment: @maartinus If you ask questions of what you want to know you earn reputation. Plenty of people earn reputation just by asking questions.

Answer (score 18):

## Don't cheat.

I'm not saying you would, just putting it here to deter anybody considering it.

There are several *apparent* weaknesses in the system where you might think you could gain extra points but most of this is automatically logged. Puppet accounts, for example, are very easy for us to spot (even with different IPs) and when we do, we can undo all the effort in a few clicks.

In short: it's not worth it and you'll just look silly.

Comment: Can this answer be placed somewhere in the FAQ?

Answer (score 10):

Edit bad spelling and grammar in questions and answers!  For every successful **and thorough** edit you make, you'll receive +2 rep (up to 2000 rep total or +1000 rep of edits, whichever comes first)

Also, if you do this: **[Don't cheat!](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1217/344926)** e.g. adding **irrelevant** tags which just takes you 2 seconds to add, but takes a reviewer 10 seconds to review is *frowned upon!*

**;-)**

Comment: Although, if it's a legit tag edit, then it's worth it.

Comment: @Daniel: nah, just tag editing is *never worth it*.

Comment: @Fabby Idk, I've seen some people add very miscellaneous tags to get more people to view their question, but that is an extreme case I guess

Comment: @DavidCole: there'll always be people gaming any system...  ;-)

Answer (score 7):

By being awesome. Look at the people with high rep, and read through their question and answer history. Emulate their awesomeness.

Comment: Can you give some suggestions for How can i emulate their "awesomeness". Yes i am really serious. I want that

Comment: @AnwarShah My specific advice is what I wrote: immerse yourself in quality by reading quality questions and answers. It should rub off on you. And the community is pretty good with constructive feedback. If you screw up with a humble attitude, people will help.