# Problem of vote restriction

Tags: discussion, privileges

Just wanted, you know that, usually amateur users read answers, not Experts. Amateurs don't post answers so their credit never increase. So those who read and test answers  cannot vote for successful one

Comment: Relevant: [Help Center Permissions Page about Upvoting](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up), including the reputation requirement for it.  (Note it's *easy* to get that 15 reputation, all one has to do is post a good question or answer and if they are a good question or answer they'll get the upvotes they need to get that reputation.)

Comment: I see your message about "Yeah this is annoying and users can't upvote".  What do you propose be done about it?  The reputation requirement for upvoting is **global**, every website has that requirement, and as I said it's extremely easy to get the 15 reputation needed to upvote things with a little bit of participation in the site.

Comment: Not true at all, I'm an amateur and I did fine here, I was not the first and I won't be the last. It really is not hard to get 15 rep to vote, just do a few edits.

Comment: See this: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1209/how-do-i-quickly-gain-reputation

Comment: @ThomasWard I see more downvote than upvote, in term of question number (but when a upvote is done, there is more chance to have over upvote again after)

Comment: @damadam that's an observation.  That's not a proposed solution.  As well, a *huge* percentage of new users post questions that are vague and unclear, and the downvotes are likely people showing disapproval with the quality of those posts.  We can't really do anything about that though.  Which goes back to the "What do you propose be done about this observation?"

Answer (score 3):

In the real world where we live, this turns out to be an advantage rather than a problem as proven during the several-year-long existence of the [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/) network.

If anyone (literally) could cast votes, the score of questions and answers would be subject to random clicks (including robots!) and therefore *less* useful than it’s now. SE has a high quality of the contents just because it is good at noise filtering. It targets quality rather than quantity.

It’s not so difficult to get the [vote-up privilege](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up) but it requires a basic understanding of the site principles and the subject. There could also be an entry test but SE allows new users to contribute to the site contents immediately instead. It is better to decide whether your actual contribution is useful than whether you can pass an artificial test with limited options.
<sub>Example: See how difficult is finding a way to create a [template](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363051/711006) or [wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369682/711006) for newbie [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) questions, although the idea is widely accepted according to the score of those posts.</sub>

Regarding your particular profile:

- You have not posted any answers yet. Answers are an easier way to get the reputation than questions.
- Your [first question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1045445/250300) does not look very clear to me and has interpunction and capitalization problems. Despite this, you got [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1046366/250300)! The [answer’s author replied](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045445/network-manager-openvpn-use-local-dns#comment1707535_1046366) to your [clarification comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045445/network-manager-openvpn-use-local-dns#comment1707493_1046366) but *you* failed to do any further actions like clarifying your problem with another comment or [accepting the answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) which would bring *you* +2 reputation!
- Your [second question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1046197/250300) (and the latest till now) is a duplicate and therefore not getting any upvotes.
- We are still waiting for your ongoing contributions!