# How can I have a LoCo team help Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, loco

So, we've got the [Global Jam](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGlobalJam) coming up, and Ask Ubuntu has around **3,600** unanswered questions.

So, I'd like to have my LoCo team help Ask Ubuntu for the jam - any particular tips/tricks that people have for tackling Ask Ubuntu in larger groups? (Also, on the same IP address - anyone had issues with 20 users, the same IP and SE's anti-cheating system?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't speak for the IP address business, but basically you can just grab the [tips and stuff that we have here in Meta already](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/257/how-does-ask-ubuntu-work) and just apply it to the entire group.

Maybe start off with a quick tutorial showing people how the site works and then just have people dive in?

Answer (score 12):

We do have an IP based rate limiter in place that *may* affect you. If you are just browsing the site normally, and posting good answers you shouldn't run into our rate limiter.

If you happen to hit the rate limiter you will see this message:

> We're sorry...
>      There are an unusual number of requests coming from this IP address.
>      To protect our users, we can't process any more requests from this IP address right now.
>      We'll restore access as quickly as possible, so try again soon.

If you run into this I would take a short break and the ban is auto cleared by our systems. If you consistently run into this message feel free to email me at: `george@stackexchange.com` and i'll see what I can do to get you guys up and running for the duration of your event.

Comment: Alrighty good stuff - if we run into it I'll bring it up.