# Questions candidates that should be closed for historical reasons?

Tags: discussion, scope, best-practice

I got [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366887/some-nice-icon-themes-for-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment469264_366887) regarding [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/65083/169736) expressing that "if that was a-ok, why mine is not". Hence to prevent further problems with these kind of questions lets close and archive it for its historical value. The answers should be candidates to be closed for these motive.

BTW, instead of "What different desktop environments and shells are available?" (which can change and is evergrowing) questions like these should be rephrased as "How to install X desktop manager?" or "How to install X shell?". This keeps the Q&A format pretty well and offers a pinpointed help to each user. Does anyone want to know 'how many X are?' Just look in the `apt-cache search X` and be dealt with.

```
$ apt-cache search "Session Manager"
gnome-session - GNOME Session Manager - GNOME 3 session
gnome-session-bin - GNOME Session Manager - Minimal runtime
gnome-session-common - GNOME Session Manager - common files
libsm-dev - X11 Session Management library (development headers)
libsm-doc - documentation for the X Session Management protocol and library
libsm6 - X11 Session Management library
libsm6-dbg - X11 Session Management library (debug package)
x11-session-utils - X session utilities
gnome-session-fallback - GNOME Session Manager - GNOME fallback session
gpe-login - login window for the G Palmtop Environment
jack-tools - various JACK tools: dl, record, scope, osc, plumbing, udp, play, transport
kde-workspace-bin - core binaries for the KDE Plasma Workspace
lxsession - default session manager for LXDE
lxsession-dbg - default session manager for LXDE - debug package
razorqt-session - Session manager component for Razor-qt desktop environment
xfce4-session - Xfce4 Session Manager
xfce4-session-dbg - Xfce4 Session Manager (debug symbols)
```

KDE, Gnome, LXDE, XFCE are there. Others may be under the name of "Window Manager" or "File manager", etc. Either way, these kind of questions *should go*.

This is the close reason:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. More info: FAQ

Maybe it could be tweaked a bit. For looking candidates I would recommend using

`https://askubuntu.com/search?q=answers%3A20` This looks for questions that has 20 answers or more.

Comment: BTW, I just check out [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1872/169736) and ought to say that it shouldn't be like that. I know AU and SU are different kind of beasts but they really don't like "software-recommendation" questions.

Answer (score 0):

About a month ago was modified since the introduction of Ubuntu GNOME Remix. There are 21 answers and I doubt it will stop as people find what they feel accustomed with and the most popular desktops are ever changing too. [What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/q/65083/169736)

Answer (score 0):

I have tons of keyboard shortcuts that makes my life more easy, I don't need a list of them nonetheless.

- [What are some useful keyboard shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1242/169736)

Answer (score 0):

Just reading the title gave me goosebumps. "you recommend" = subjective. `apt-cache search "time track*"` gave as results 8 of 20, I say if I used aptitude/synaptic/USC I would have got more (also that my search term kinda sucks).

- [Which Time Tracker application do you recommend?](https://askubuntu.com/q/4113/169736)