# How come my questions aren't being answered?

Tags: support

why aren't my questions being answered? It seems like they aren't noticed... Most of my questions have no answers or votes. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/257/how-does-ask-ubuntu-work) and especially read the first answer, section **How to ask good questions**.  You ask very short questions, which are unanswerable with the info you give, except [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/735608/my-wireless-is-very-slow) which is a duplicate waiting to happen. (Just my 2 cents. Disclosure: I'm not a mod)