# I would like a moderator to remove the acceptance from one of my answers and give it to another one

Tags: support, answers

*Is that even possible?*

Question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593938/how-to-run-both-intel-and-nvidia-graphics-card-driver-on-dual-monitor-setup) with my answer the accepted one and the one below that a better one!

Yeah, I've looked [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/252/how-do-i-demote-my-own-answer-and-encourage-people-to-see-the-more-detailed-one) already but I'm not going to plagiarise the better one; that would feel totally wrong!

Yeah, I tried deleting my own answer, but as it's the accepted one, I cannot...  **:-(**

Comment: P.S. No, I don't care losing 15 rep...  **:-)**

Comment: As I am informed, accepting an answer is 100% the OP's personal subjective selection. It is not possible for the community or even moderators to change acceptance on behalf of another user. The only chance I see here is that you delete your answer yourself (although it could be that the accept mark blocks you from deleting it yourself, not sure - in that case a mod could probably delete it for you).

Comment: Yup, tried deleting before I posted the question...  Will add that to the Q.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Accepting answers is 100% the original question poster's opinion.  We don't mess with that.  We also can't unaccept an answer or force answer acceptance.  The community can't really, either.  (Evidence: [my answer on "Easiest way to setup Ubuntu as a VPN server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119534/easiest-way-to-setup-ubuntu-as-a-vpn-server/305401#305401), the +500 bounty I was awarded on it by posting a working answer long after an accepted answer was there, and the fact the 'accepted' answer has been flagged to be removed multiple times with all of those times being declined, from what I can tell)

We also tend to try and *avoid* deleting accepted answers, whether they're wrong or not.  I'd add a blurb to your post as an edit that "Note: the other answer here is better, consider using that one instead" and link to it.  I've had to do this at times myself in the past.

Sorry, but I'm not comfortable sniping an answer simply because one is 'better' whether yours or not.  Especially when it's already accepted - we try and leave that to the 'community'.  (There's only a few cases where I'd torch an answer that's already accepted, and that's usually only if the now-accepted answer is going to cause seriously horrible things or now links to malware or something)

Comment: Done!  Stop editing your answer and pussyfooting around the fact that your hammer is just a rubber one!  **>:-)  :D :D :D ;-)**

Comment: Surely we should try to remove an accepted answer if it really is completely *wrong*

Comment: @Zanna flat out wrong?  Probably.  But "okay but inferior to another answer" while still being fairly "right"?  Yeah that's usually the grey area and is case-by-case.  However I don't think that Fabby's answer actually *is* wrong so...

Comment: @ThomasWard I thought OP can change the accepted answer. Isn't that the case?

Comment: Sure, I wasn't referring to Fabby's answer, just wanting to be sure about the general comment :)

Comment: @Zanna True.  But if it's wrong only because of the *age* of the question (say a Chrubuntu question for example) then it's not just going to be 'removed', just because it is *now* incorrect - at the *time* it helped, but age changed things.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, mods cannot change accepted answers. See [this Meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18312/moderators-accepting-answers-on-users-behalf-after-a-certain-time-period), as well as [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78438/blatantly-wrong-accepted-answer) and [this one too](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6171/is-it-possible-for-moderators-to-accept-an-answer)

So yeah, I don't believe they can do that. <s>Unless, of course, @ThomasWard infuses his *hammer of power* with some TNT or C4 :D</s>

Comment: Let's wait and see if Thomas can delete an accepted answer if I ask for it myself!  (Now we'll know how heavy his hammer *really* is...)  Moohahahaha!

Answer (score 0):

Came across this while searching for another topic.  Old, old question I know.  It looks like, since you hit 20k rep at some point, you were able to delete your answer yourself?

Personally, in this case, I would just recommending editing your answer (which I'm assuming is still the accepted one, even if deleted)  to point to the one you feel is a better solution.  Something like:

> After posting this, *[@xyx]* (I'm assuming @MikaDo-) posted what I believe is a better solution *[link to that answer]*.  I would recommend following that solution rather than mine because *[reason(s) why the other answer is better]*.

Since the OP of the question hasn't visited the site since then, it's unlikely that the accepted answer will ever changed, but that gives you the ability to "redirect" others to what you believe is the correct answer.

You can, of course, either leave your answer below that as an alternative or just keep it in the edit history.